# Java Multicast doesnt work in windows

Tags: java, windows, udp, multicast, lan

I have this code but it doens't work in 2 diferent computers, I changed my firewall but it doesnt work.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.MulticastSocket;
import java.rmi.RMISecurityManager;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TestingDota{

private static String name;
public static void main(String args[]){
    name = args[0];

    final InetAddress group;
    final String address = "230.0.0.1";
    final int port = 9876;
    try{
        group = InetAddress.getByName(address);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;
    }
    HashMap<String, Tupla> map = new HashMap<String,Tupla>();
    try{
        final MulticastSocket socket = new MulticastSocket(port);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
        socket.joinGroup(group);
        socket.setTimeToLive(2);
        new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                while(true){
                    String msg = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName()+ "," + name;
                    DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), group, port);
                    try {
                        socket.send(packet);
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (IOException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
        }.start();

        while(true){
            byte[] buf = new byte[512];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            String msg = new String(packet.getData()).trim();
            int index = msg.indexOf(',');
            String key = msg.substring(0,index);
            String name = msg.substring(index+1, msg.length());
            long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
            if(map.containsKey(key)){
                Tupla t = map.get(key);
                t.time = time;
            }else{
                Tupla t = new Tupla();
                t.name = name;
                t.time = time;
                map.put(key, t);
                mostrar(map);
            }
            int size = map.size();
            ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            for(String k : map.keySet()){
                Tupla t = map.get(k);
                if(time - t.time> 1500 ){
                    list.add(k);
                }
            }
            for(String x : list) map.remove(x);
            if(size > map.size()){
                mostrar(map);
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void mostrar(HashMap<String, Tupla> map) {
    for(String k : map.keySet()){
        Tupla t = map.get(k);
        System.out.println(t.name);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

static class Tupla{
    String name;
    long time;
}
}
```

To run this program please write: $ java TestingDota someName, it works with several terminals in the same computer, but it doesnt work in diferent computers

Comment: It could be your router. AFAIK, most home routers, and even some enterprise-class routers do not implement IP Multicast.

Comment: Calling setReuseAddress() after you have already bound the socket to the port accomplishes precisely nothing.

Answer (score 0):

230.0.0.1 is a [reserved multicast address](http://www.iana.org/assignments/multicast-addresses/multicast-addresses.xml#multicast-addresses-9). You can't use it.

Comment: I changed it but it doesnt work, could you please give an example of a god ip

Comment: @user1351870 It depends what you changed it to, doesn't it? When you read the page I linked to you should have found the answer to your question.